# smbclient NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE against Windows Server 2012 R2 share

Tags: samba, windows-server-2012-r2

We are running Debian wheezy, with smbclient v 3.6.6, trying to reach a Windows 2012 R2 share.

This conundrum involves two users: ReadOnlyUser and WriteUser

We have been using -A (--authentication-file) to reach our windows shares from this box for years in order to automate many file transfer jobs against various Windows shares, sftp, and web endpoints. I can use the -A option to log in with the ReadOnlyUser against this share without difficulty.

`smbclient '//server.domain/share' -A ReadOnlyUser.auth`

I can use -U to log in with the WriteUser if I provide the password in response to the prompt interactively.

`smbclient '//server.domain/share' -U WriteUser`

However, when I try to provide an authentication file with the WriteUser credentials, I get this error: `session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

The authentication files look like this:

> username = WriteUser
>   password = 3iDPCAWmdiAQxTn3
>   domain = mydomain

I checked in our AD to make sure that the two users are identical in all other respects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue which has been reported on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1318835

The symptom of smbclient seems to ignore the "domain" section in your credentials file, so that -A doesn't override /etc/samba/smb.conf。The workaround based on the issue report is you have to modify WORKGROUP in smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = mydomain
```

So that you can keep using -A  to access SMB server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with smbclient, and I noticed that it went away when I manually selected the "Just Enable File Sharing" option on the File Sharing dialog you get after manually right-clicking on the folder you want to share.

In some Windows machines (like Windows XP) you need to add this to permit remote sharing for non guest users:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\forceguest=dword:0
```

or, automating using the windows xp command line:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" /v forceguest /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
```

After that, smbclient worked without any problems with any user.

Many thanks to jethomas in http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/enable-file-sharing-via-the-command-line-133562.html